# jQuery, Open a dialog when mouse is hover a icon

Tags: jquery

I need to open a dialog when mouse is hover an icon. This dialog box can be opened on the icon.

Currently, I use the events .mouseenter and .mouseout.
The problem is that the event .mouseout is triggered when the dialog box opens on the icon.

What is the best solution?

edit: my code:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".t_tun_exp_img", function() {
    let $img = $(this);

    let timeout = null;
    $img.mouseout(function() { clearTimeout(timeout); $img.off("mouseout"); });

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $($img.data("explication")).dialog({
            width: 1000,
            dialogClass: "noTitleStuff",
            create: function() {
                let $dialog = $(this);
                $img.mouseout(function() {
                    $dialog.dialog("destroy");
                    $img.off("mouseout");
                });
            }
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is adding `pointer-events: none;` style on dialog box.

In Your case it should solve the problem:

```
.noTitleStuff {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```